# My C Program is not executing fully, it's stopping midway. Question is taking elements of array from user and calculating sum of each column in array

Tags: arrays, c, malloc

The Question is to take dimension of array and elements of it from the user. Then calculate the sum of each column in array, it stops midway for some reason. I am new to C, is there a problem in usig malloc not in right way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int m,n;
    int arr[m][n];
    int **arr;
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter Number of Rows and Columns:\t");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    arr=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*m);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    }


    printf("Type Array Elements:\t");

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("This is Where It Stops");
    //ADDITION OF COLUMNS
    int Sum;
    int *sum=(int*)malloc(j*sizeof(int));
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            Sum=0;
            Sum=Sum+arr[i][j];
        }
        sum[j]=Sum;
    }
    for(j<0;j<0;j++)
    {
        printf("Sum of Column %d is %d", j, sum[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(j<0;j<0;j++)` - take a real close look at this. And remove `a`, it is not used and the declaration doesn't make sense.

Comment: and anyway `int a[m][n];` should be below `scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);` The `m` and `n` have indeterminate values at the present location.